# Application User form is inactive in a Dynamics 365 environment

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, power-platform, dynamics-365-sales

I want to create an application user in my Dynamics 365 Environment.
On the Security -> Users -> Application Users -> New User, the Application user form is not present.

I checked in Customize my System -> User Form. The Application user form was inactive.
I activated the form.
However, when I tried to publish all customizations, I was thrown an error:

> Insufficient PermissionsPrincipal user (Id=<>, type=8, roleCount=2, privilegeCount=564, accessMode=1(Setup/Stub user with filtered privileges from associated roles. Consider changing user AccessMode to Full (without privilege filtering))), is missing prvReadAppModule privilege (Id=<>) on OTC=9006 for entity 'appmodule'. context.Caller=<>. Or identityUser.SystemUserId=<>, identityUser.Privileges.Count=3016, identityUser.Roles.Count=0 is missing prvReadAppModule privilege (Id=<>) on OTC=<>for entity 'appmodule'. If you contact support, please provide the technical details.

My user account has the "Dynamics 365 Customer Service Enterprise" License assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, your CRM user profile has System Administrator or System Customizer before publishing any customizations.

Also, CAL Access mode should be either Administrative or Read-Write.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved by going into 'classic' Dynamics UI (the really old one with ribbon nav bar), selecting 'Customizations', On customizations page, select 'Customize the system', then browsed to the entity with the form that was inactive, selected 'All Forms' from the pulldown and then selected new form I wanted to activate and selected 'Activate' ...
[ACTIVATE FORM IN CLASSIC UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmCKj.png)